# Is this a VC11 compile bug?

Tags: c++, lambda, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++

I am using vs2012(vc11) writing a c++ program. When i am trying to use a bit complicated lambda expression.

```
    RasDial(NULL, NULL, 0, 0, &[=]()
    {
    RasDial(NULL, NULL, 0, 0, &[=](){}, 0);
    }, 0);
```

Then the compile gave me an error: C2101 & on constant. And i changed place, then the code like this:

```
RasDial(NULL, NULL, 0, 0, &[=](){
    auto func = [=](){};
    RasDial(NULL, NULL, 0, 0,&func, 0);
}, 0);
```

By Comparison, You can compile those following expression successfully:

```
RasDial(NULL,NULL,0,0,&[](){},0);
```

I infer that the VC compile cannot understand nested lambda with & well.

Then vc11 can successfully compile it.
Does that mean its a vc11 compile bug?

Comment: Taking address of a lambda seems strange anyway.

Comment: I think you can just get rid of the ampersand entirely and rely on the conversion from captureless lambda to function pointer.